# Clearing the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellName-%d", [indexPath row]];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        // etc
    }
}
```

I want to clear all the cells I've stored up since the table data has changed so they need to be regenerated. I am storing all the cells in this way deliberately.

I am wondering is there a way/method to dumb all the cells that are alive, that are related to a particular table.

Regards,
-Code

Comment: Why are you storing the cells in that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, also you when I look at your code you aren't using any of the dequeued cells since you create a new cell for every row in you tableview.

This would mean then if you have a 1000 cells in your table a 1000 tabelviewcells are created. This will make you tableview very slow, also it will take up to musch memory.

When cells look the same should all give then the same `cellIdentifier`, then just fill the cell with the data from you data source. 
You should only create a new cell when the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` does not return any cells.

Then when `[self.tableView reloadData]` is called you just read the new value from the datasource and fill them in in the tableview cell.

You datasource is the place to stored state and not cells, because I can't think of any other reason to have your datasource work this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ([tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseid"]) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have been battling with this too, the solution is to remove the table view from superview and release it completely, so the tableview is dealloc-ed

```
[self.tableView removeFromSuperview];
```

And than recreate a new TableView... this is kind of brutal, but i needed this to remove costly cells with uiwebviews

Answer (score -1):

I think UITableView has method [tableView reloadData] which clear all cells. When i make app in which data is appended in tableview. i calle this method.